# Store.reload() ->How to Query by lastParam in ExtJs4

Tags: extjs4, store

I have a Grid.
Get Data Code
Code:

```
var myParam = {
   typeId : 1,
   xxxx : 'xxxx' //some else 
}
grid.store.load(myParam);
```

When to do something such as time renovate
Code:

```
grid.store.reload();
```

But this lost param.

In ExtJs3 have a Config of LastParam . 
How to do in Extjs4.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

use the proxy's extraParams config.

```
grid.store.getProxy().extraParams = myParam;
grid.store.load();
grid.store.reload();
```

This way the params will be sent until you modify the extra param again with code.